# Cannot get External Node Classifier in puppet working - bash and java

Tags: java, bash, puppet

I have the following script where I call a java program that writes a YAML output to Strandard output stream, and that is echoed (Simple).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -jar /etc/puppet/enc/enc.jar $1`
```

I have the above script in file

```
/etc/puppet/enc/javaEnc.sh
```

When I execute this providing node name as argument I get the following output.

```
---
classes:
  class1:
  class2:
```

The problem is, on the agent node, I get the error message

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find node 'node-agent-1'; cannot compile
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I have found that the script does not execute (or rather my java program is not called, don't know why) - In my java program I write the output to a file in addition to doing a System.out.print.

I have a another script where I read the file (data.yaml) that contains the same data as I mentioned as output and writes it to output stream by following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "/etc/puppet/enc/data.yaml"
```

When this script is mentioned against external_nodes, it works fine, the puppet agent configures itself. Can I please get an idea where I am getting it wrong.? The java program actually queries some external resources and classifies the classes and produces the output - it takes around 10 seconds to get this done. Could this be a problem ? I have seen ruby and python solutions - couldn't get them to work either. I would like it done with Java most preferably.

In my puppet.conf file I have the following.

```
[master]
node_terminus = exec
external_nodes = /etc/puppet/enc/javaEnc.sh
```

Comment: can you post the output of your java script by running that on a terminal as user "puppet" ?

Comment: I get the message `This account is currently not available.` when I execute doing this `su -  puppet /etc/puppet/enc/javaEnc.sh node-agent-1`.

However, I tried the code from [niclasmeier](https://github.com/niclasmeier/puppet-ec2-enc/blob/master/ec2_enc.rb), and changed the ownership of that script to puppet. It worked. I get the same message `This account is currently not available.` when I try to run it as user puppet, but it works when a request come from agent (The agent configures itself).

Comment: Does it mean, it works on the puppet client but not on master ? I am a bit confused what works and what doesn't and where !

Comment: The ruby solution from [niclasmeier](https://github.com/niclasmeier/puppet-ec2-enc/blob/master/ec2_enc.rb), works and it only need to be on master - just that I had to change its ownership from root to puppet. My solution (calling a java program from bash) doesn't work.